# How to convert the column in order by linq

Tags: vb.net, casting, linq-to-entities, sql-order-by

Select Year
From MyTable
Order By Cast( [Year] as Int ) Desc

Same thing I am trying to do in the linq order by.  It's not working.
I have column that is defined in the data base as string (Varchar) and I need to cast/convert it to integer before I need to sort it.  What should be my linq statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the reasons of storing year as `char`?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
Dim q = (from p in Data.Instance.Context.MyTable 
         select p).OrderBy(Function(p)Convert.ToInt32(p.Year))
```

The above query was extracted from [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_23099300.html).